# VS Code application will not open

Tags: windows-8.1, visual-studio-code

I have installed VS Code (v. 0.9.2) on Windows 8.1. When I try to open the application nothing happens. I see that it opens and the closes right away while looking in the task manger. I have tried everything I can think of to fix this. Uninstalling, reinstalling, rebooted....

Has anyone else had an issue with this?

Comment: Can you please try to run `code.exe --verbose` directly out of the installation directory via command prompt to see if anything is printed to the console?

Comment: So I had to reinstall VS Code in order to get the output you were looking for. This time everything worked. Not sure what the issue was yesterday. Maybe a bad installer or something. I'm not sure if the VS Code team does nightly builds or not but whatever changed over night fixed the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-downloaded the installer again, 15 hours later than initial install, and installed. The application opens now.